# Taking variable names out of column and creating new columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to take a dataframe like this

```
    name        response
 1   Phil        Exam
 2   Terry       Test
 3   Simmon      Exam
 4   Brad        Quiz
```

And turn it into this

```
    name        response    Exam    Test   Quiz
   1 Phil        Exam        Exam  
   2 Terry       Test                Test
   3 Simmon      Exam        Exam
   4 Brad        Quiz                       Quiz
```

I tried to use a for loop, extracting each row. Then I would check to see if the column already existed and if it did not it would create a new column. I couldnt get this close to working and am unsure how to do this.

Comment: Essentially a model matrix - `cbind(dat, model.matrix(~ response + 0, data=dat))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished a few ways. Might be a good opportunity to get to know the tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
new.df <- spread(old.df, response, response)
```

This is an unusual use of `tidyr::spread()`. In this case, it constructs new column names from the values in "response", and also fills those columns with the values in "response". The `fill` argument can be used to change what goes in the resulting blank cells.

Comment: I was on my way to posting the same.  Glad I refreshed.

Comment: @rss1080 If this works, please accept this post as the answer.

Comment: Would you happen to have a method that can merge spread variables? For example if I run spread again on a different column, and that different column also contains Exam, Exam will then be sorted into the previously made Exam column?

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution. We can create a function to replace words that do not match to the target word, and then create the new column to the data frame.

```
# Create example data frame
dt <- read.table(text = "    name        response
 1   Phil        Exam
 2   Terry       Test
 3   Simmon      Exam
 4   Brad        Quiz", 
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# A function to create a new column based on the word in response
create_Col <- function(word, df, fill = NA){
  new <- df$response
  new[!new == word] <- fill
  return(new)
} 

# Apply this function
for (i in unique(dt$response)){
  dt[[i]] <- create_Col(word = i, df = dt)
}

dt
    name response Exam Test Quiz
1   Phil     Exam Exam <NA> <NA>
2  Terry     Test <NA> Test <NA>
3 Simmon     Exam Exam <NA> <NA>
4   Brad     Quiz <NA> <NA> Quiz
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), name + response ~ response, value.var = 'response', fill = "")
#     name response Exam Quiz Test
#1:   Brad     Quiz      Quiz     
#2:   Phil     Exam Exam          
#3: Simmon     Exam Exam          
#4:  Terry     Test           Test
```