# Taking variable names out of column and creating a new column value based on condition

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr

I have this matrix df with in the first column all the words and in column 2-75 different LIWC categories the words fall into.

A toy example here of what I have:

| word | posemo | certain | insight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| certainly | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| obviously | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| sure | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| directly | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| insight | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| guarantee | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| prove | 1 | 0 | 1 |

This is what I want to achieve:

| word | posemo | certain | insight | Categories |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| certainly | 1 | 0 | 1 | posemo, insight |
| obviously | 1 | 1 | 1 | posemo, certain, insight |
| sure | 1 | 0 | 0 | posemo |
| directly | 1 | 0 | 1 | posemo,insight |
| insight | 1 | 1 | 0 | posemo, certain |
| guarantee | 0 | 1 | 0 | certain |
| prove | 1 | 0 | 1 | posemo, insight |

I have been looking all over stackoverflow, but I can't seem to find something that applies to what I'm trying to do. This one [Taking variable names out of column and creating new columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46438119/taking-variable-names-out-of-column-and-creating-new-columns-in-r) comes close, but doesn't deal with conditions.

Any tips? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `apply`:

```
data.frame( dat, Categories=t(
   t( apply( dat[,2:4], 1, function(x) colnames(dat[,2:4])[as.logical(x)] ) ) ))

       word posemo certain insight               Categories
1 certainly      1       0       1          posemo, insight
2 obviously      1       1       1 posemo, certain, insight
3      sure      1       0       0                   posemo
4  directly      1       0       1          posemo, insight
5   insight      1       1       0          posemo, certain
6 guarantee      0       1       0                  certain
7     prove      1       0       1          posemo, insight
```

**Data**

```
dat <- structure(list(word = c("certainly", "obviously", "sure", "directly", 
"insight", "guarantee", "prove"), posemo = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L), certain = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), insight = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

EDIT for speed, try pre-defining crucial data

```
n <- colnames( dat[,2:4] )
lo <- dat[,2:4] == 1

data.frame( dat, Categories=t(t( apply( lo, 1, function(x) n[x] ) ) ))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really great! This works on the toy example, but takes forever to load for the whole df which has 60.000 rows. Good thing I have time today :)

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

Loop over the rows and find which rows are equal to 1 (`cols <- x[i,] == 1`) then get those column names (`cats <- na.omit(colnames(x)[cols])`) then paste them together as a single string and replace the value of `categories` (`x$categories[i] <- paste(cats, collapse = ", ")`)

```
x <- tibble(word = c("love","hate","sad"),
            happy = c(1,0,0),
            sad = c(0,1,1),
            emotion = c(1,1,1),
            categories = c(NA,NA,NA))

for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
  cols <- x[i,] == 1
  cats <- na.omit(colnames(x)[cols])
  x$categories[i] <- paste(cats, collapse = ", ")
}
```